# How to check if form field is hidden with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, gravity

I need to do a simple boolean condition on a form field. Basically I just need to know if field #xxx is hidden or not.

I think this is the right approach but I'm not sure because I not getting my desired results.

```
if($("#input_<?php echo $form["id"]; ?>_27[type='hidden']").val() == '') {
// the field has no value so let's break out of this
break;
}
```

I'm adding a hook to gravity forms in Wordpress. I need this hook to work on all forms because this form may be duplicated, however if a new form is created that contains the same field ID but is NOT hidden I don't want to continue the jQuery function.

EDIT: I added the GF id being passed by the hook for more accuracy. I realized after I posted this that if I duplicated that form the field id would change.

SOLVED: Using Shivam's answer below I got it. For anyone interested entire hook is here:

```
<?php
add_filter('gform_pre_render', 'replace_cn');
function replace_cn($form){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var cname =  $("#input_<?php echo $form["id"]; ?>_27[type='hidden']").val();
            if (!$("#input_<?php echo $form["id"]; ?>_27").is(":hidden")) {
                return;
            }
            var placeholder = '[XX]';
            jQuery("*").each(function () {
                if (jQuery(this).children().length == 0) {
                    jQuery(this).text($(this).text().replace(placeholder,cname));
                }
            });
            jQuery("label").each(function () {
jQuery(this).html($(this).html().replace(placeholder,cname));
            });         
        });
    </script>
<?php
return $form;
}
?>
```

Comment: you will end up having problems if you are going to have duplicate IDs

Comment: I just edited my OP. I totally forgot I needed the form ID to be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#input_3_27").is(":hidden")
```

Also more secure way to achieve same effect is:

```
('#yourID').attr('type') == 'hidden'; // this will also return a boolean
```

EDIT: By secure I mean, the `.is(:hidden)` will still work if you style the element with `display:none`.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks I knew there was a more elegant solution. I modified it slightly to add the dynamic form ID. Cheers! In 9 minutes I can mark this as the answer :)

Comment: What do you mean secure? As in vulnerability or consistency in selection?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blurfus/zWN8z/1)

```
$("input[type='hidden']").val()
```

Comment: Just edited it. Thanks blurfus but it still seemed to work without the single quotes.